# How do I delete a line at the end of the file and put it at the top of the file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, filesystems, fs

Here's my current code:

```js
const rl = require("readline");
const fs = require("fs");

const ri = rl.createInterface({
  input: fs.createReadStream("dot-error.log"),
  output: process.stdout,
  console: false,
});

ri.on("line", function (line: string) {
  const append: string = line.substring(line.indexOf("\n") + 1);   
});
```

How would I make a for loop that grabs the line at the end of the file in dot-error.log and paste it add the top of the file and delete that line (at the end of the file? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

delete last line then put on top

```
var fs = require("fs");

var lines = fs.readFileSync("dot-error.log", 'utf8'); // read the file
lines = lines.trim().split('\n'); // remove empty lines and split using \n
var lastLine = lines.pop() // get last line
lines.unshift(lastLine); // prepend last line
fs.writeFileSync("dot-error.log", lines.join('\n')); // write
```

edit: to reverse the order

```
var lines = fs.readFileSync("dot-error.log", 'utf8');
lines = lines.trim().split('\n');
lines.reverse();
fs.writeFileSync("dot-error.log", lines.join('\n'));
```